# Python SFTP - command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, pixel, raspbian

Raspbeery Pi3
Raspbian Jessie Pixel (latest)
Python 3.4

I know i can push commands to terminal from Python. But i wanted to use a more Python-centric approach that could possibly be updated later on on another system.

I am trying to install PySFTp, but i keep getting stuck. I am installed the dependencies one at a time. So first its PyCrypto then Paramiko then PySFTP.

PyCrypto installs fine, but Paramiko is where I am having an issue. 
This is the command i use:

```
    sudo pip3 install Paramiko
```

This is the error i get:

```
    compilation terminated.
error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have googled and checked and I believe I have installed all the Python3-dev stuff necessary along with using this command:

```
    apt-cache search gnutls | grep dev
```

My friend told me to install all the things on that list, that still did not work.

I have even downloaded the whl files and tar files and gone through those and it still did not work. I am relatively new to this stuff and know its something that is missing from my OS. but have no idea where to start.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: There should be a more detailed error message earlier in the output or in the log pip is writing.

Comment: There was, my apologies for not adding it.

Answer (score 8):

I did the most obvious thing in the world and it worked, silly old me.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

I did uninstall a lot of things while trying to fault find so to be on the same side I did the below, not needed for all but I did it anyway.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc libffi-dev libssl-dev python3-dev
```

I was then able to install:

- `Pycrypto`
- `Paramiko`
- `PySFTP`

Answer (score 0):

I have installed

sudo apt install python-dev and it worked for me !!

Actually i got this problem in rasperry pi 3